# Why is starting a Blaze server that supports websockets different than a server that does not support it in Http4s

Tags: scala, websocket

Here is the sample code to start a Blaze server that supports websockets in http4s:

https://github.com/http4s/http4s/blob/master/examples/blaze/src/main/scala/com/example/http4s/blaze/BlazeWebSocketExample.scala#L53

It is quite different than in the case where websocket support is not required:

https://github.com/http4s/http4s/blob/master/examples/blaze/src/main/scala/com/example/http4s/blaze/BlazeExample.scala#L8

Why is this the case? Would it possible to add a `withWebsocketSupport` on `BlazeBuilder`?

I mean, if the API can be improved, that's great, but I am trying to understand how websocket support fits into the picture because I am having issues getting my web server (that supports websockets) to function properly.

Comment: It appears that the linked files may have changed in the time since you asked this question.